# Rails 5.2/Yarn: What is the correct way to import CCS from a node module?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, yarnpkg

I have added `toastr` using Yarn.

I have no problem importing the JS. However, in production, the CSS will not load. It works fine in development, just not in production.

I'm importing it like so:

```
# application.scss
@import "bootstrap";
@import "rails_bootstrap_forms";
@import "toastr/build/toastr.css";
@import "styles.scss";
```

As I've said, it works in development but when running on the production server, I can see Rails is looking for the file in the assets folder:

```
http://bglomhook.herokuapp.com/assets/toastr/build/toastr.css
```

Short of copying the css into the assets folder, is there a way I can ensure Rails finds the file?

Answer (score 1):

You need 2 things:

1. Make sure `node_modules` are installed, i.e. you should have a `yarn install` somewhere in your deployment script.
2. Make the asset pipeline aware of `node_modules`. This can be done by adding `node_modules` to the assets paths, in `assets.rb`: `config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('node_modules')`

You can find more info [here](https://ricostacruz.com/til/npm-in-rails)

Comment: I already have both of those things. I've double checked and can confirm `toastr` is installed in the `node_modules` directory on heroku. Also, I already have the line `Rails.application.config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('node_modules')` in `initializers/assets`.